# How to convert Ruby data structure to a HTML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Stack overflow so kindly excuse if my question deviates from the expected standard.

I processed a log file to a below format and I would like to form a HTML representation from the below data structure.

```
holder = [ 

{:states=>"Texas"}
{:cities=>"Antonio", :data=>{"Ron"=>"26", "Rock"=>"23", "Jake"=>"33"}}
{:cities=>"West_CIT", :data=>{}}
{:cities=>"Austin", :data=>{"Ron"=>"26", "Mike"=>"53", "Jake"=>"36"}}

{:states=>"California"}
{:cities=>"Sacramento", :data=>{"Jill"=>"584", "Rudy"=>"3"}}
{:cities=>"Los Angeles", :data=>{"Jill"=>"4", "Rudy"=>"2"}}

{:states=>"Georgia"}
{:cities=>"Atlanta", :data=>{"Ron"=>"6", "Ross"=>"2", "Jake"=>"35"}}
{:cities=>"Athens", :data=>{"Jill"=>"16", "Mike"=>"4", "Reeves"=>"8"}} ]
```

I'm trying to create a HTML file which displays the States **only** on the Top page, like below

```
 <h1> States and Associate Demat details <h1>
 Texas
 California
 Georgia
```

but on clicking any State it should expand to a below format holding the sub details

```
Texas
Antonio     Ron      26
            Rock      23
            Jake     33

West_CIT   

Austin     Ron        26
           Mike       53
           Jake       36

California
Georgia
Likewise the other states.
```

I've gone thru the Ruby documentation as well as the Nokogiri gem but with my limited knowledge in ruby (or any programming language) hampers my progress.. Is it really possible with Ruby or should I go with PHP (learn again). Looking for the guidance here, thank you.

P.S I've taken this as a self assignment in an attempt to improve my Ruby (or programming skills)

What I wrote :

```
holder = []
counter = -1

text = File.open("states.log").read
text.each_line do |line|
  line.strip!
  next if line.empty?
  next if line.include?('persons') || line.include?('demat')
  next if ['-','*'].include? line[0]
  chip = line.split ' '
   if chip.size == 1 and line.start_with?('state')
    holder[counter += 1] = {states: line, data: {}}
    next
  elsif chip.size == 1 and chip = /^(?!.*state_).*$/
    holder[counter += 1] = {cities: line, data: {}}
    next
  end

  chip.each_cons(2) do |key, value|
    holder[counter][:data][key] = value 
    end
end

puts holder
```

Adding the sample log file (raw)

```
state_Texas

Antonio

persons                 demat
------------------------------ ----------
Ron                    26
Ron                    23
Jake                   33

=========================================

----Persons

West_CIT

persons                 demat
------------------------------ ----------

=========================================

----Persons

Austin


persons                 demat
------------------------------ ----------
Ron                    26
Mike                   53
Jake                   36

=========================================
state_California

Sacramento


persons                 demat
------------------------------ ----------
Jill                   584
Rudy                   3

=========================================

---- Persons
Los Angeles


persons                 demat
------------------------------ ----------
Jill                   4
Rudy                   2

=========================================

Likewise .......
```

Comment: Look for erb: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

Comment: @iGian:  Thank you for introducing me to the ERB :)  Could you kindly let me know how can I format my code here.. Sorry for asking your time here but that will help to kick start here.. Like how can I loop the data into a ERB template .. Thanks again !!

Comment: You'll get warnings when you run this script.  The Holder variable should not start with a capital letter as it will be parsed as a constant in Ruby.

Comment: @BenTrewern : Thank You, I have changed to the lower case.. Still learning the nuances of efficient coding :)

Comment: Now there is the raw log file. Maybe you want to share also the code that you have written to process and which returns the `holder` variable. Maybe just little changes can do the trick.

Comment: @iGian : I have already updated the  code in my question, many thanks for looking into it..

Comment: @iGian : My apologies to bother you, I've tried other approaches to get a HTML file of aforementioned format but I failed, tried ERB, direct - file.puts but nothing worked.. Any help would be really helpful, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you, but I must find some time. Is `----Persons` or ` ---- Persons` the correct separating string? Or both?

Comment: @iGian :Really thanks a lot, `----Persons`  is the correct string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first: if you need to exchange data between applications I suggest to stick with standard formats like `JSON` or `YAML`. I don't know if you can control the data logging, but if you can, I suggest to change the code there.

That log file is really a mess but it contains enough information for convert it into a ruby data structure like arrays and hashes.

There is always a better way but I ended up with this solution.

```
REJECT_THIS = ["", "------------------------------ ----------", "----Persons", "---- Persons", "persons demat"]
holder = []
separator = '|||'

# here we store the file into the holder, skipping rows in REJECT_THIS
text = File.open("_states.log").read
text.each_line do |line|
  line = line.split.join(' ')
  holder << line unless REJECT_THIS.include? line
end

# just to change the separator mark into a shorter one
holder.map! { |e| e == "=========================================" ? separator : e} 

# map where to split the array grouping by state
split_idxs = holder.map.with_index { |e, i| e [0..4] == 'state' ? i : 0}.uniq[1..-1]<<holder.size

# split the array in states using the index map using the my_split_at_index method and building the states hash
holder = holder.my_split_at_index(split_idxs).map { |element| {element.shift => element} }

# remove 'state_' and convert the key to symbol
holder.map! { |e| e.transform_keys { |key| key[6..-1].to_sym } }

# splits subarrays by separator then build the nested hash
holder.map! do |array|
  array.transform_values do |sub_array|
    split_idxs = sub_array.map.with_index { |e, i| e == separator ? i : 0 }.uniq[1..-1]
    sub_array = sub_array.my_split_at_index(split_idxs).map! { |e| e[0] == separator ? e[1..-1] : e }
    sub_array.map { |element| {city: element.shift, people: element} }
  end
end

# splits the people string
holder.map do |state|
  state.transform_values do |array|
    array.map do |hash|
      hash[:people].map! { |string| string.split(' ') }
    end
  end
end

p holder
```

In the code I used this Array monkey patch

```
class Array

  def my_split_at_index(indexes = [])
    shift = 0
    splitted = []
    indexes.map do |index|
      splitted << self[shift..index-1]
      shift = index
    end
    splitted
  end

end
```

The variable holder now is an array of nested hashes that you can use with ERB in a code like Dan Hilton posted. The data structure of holder is not the same, so you need to tweak the code.

One last thing, to see how the structure of your data as a `YAML` looks:

```
require 'yaml'
puts holder.to_yaml
```

Comment: Really Really appreciate the time you have taken to help me here :) Thanks much, I got a picture now :)  
My upvote isn't getting reflected

Answer (score 0):

As iGian said you can use ERB templates to create your HTML. I would also recommend changing your data structure to be easier to iterate. You are currently using the array order to determine where the cities are. This requires additional checks on the template side. Instead, the cities should be nested in the states hash to look like: `{:state => "Texas", :cities=>[{:name => "Antonio", :data=>{"Ron"=>"26", "Rock"=>"23", "Jake"=>"33"}]}`. This way you have an array of cities for a given state. Using this data structure, your template would look something like:

```
template = ERB.new <<-EOF
    <h1> States and Associate Demat details <h1>
    <% Holder.each do |state| %>
        <h2><%= state[:state] %></h2>
        <% state[:cities].each do |city| %>
            <h3><%= city[:name] %></h3>
            <% city[:data].each do |name, value| %>
                <%= name %> - <%= value %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
EOF
```

Note that using `<%= %>` with the `=` is used to wrap ruby expressions that you want to show up on your template. On the other hand `<% %>` is used to set variables and iterate through your data structure, but will not show up in your template.

In your case, the use of templating is probably overkill and you can get away with using `File.write('index.html')` but getting ERB practice is useful because it will be directly applicable if you decide to learn Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Thank you but any chance ERB can be applied for my existing data structure , thanks.. Im going thru the ERB documentation and its kinda confusing for a novice.

Comment: or is it possible to convert my existing data structure to the format you've mentioned.. any examples would be really helpful

Comment: Yes, it can be applied but you'd need to do some control flow based on whether the key is :states or :cities. I've outlined a fair amount of different ways to iterate through arrays and hashes in my answer so try to use that as a guideline. Note that any valid ruby can be in the template like <% if hash[:states] %>..<% end %>

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112264/string-to-hash-in-ruby-without-json-parse this can help converting your data string to hash

Comment: @hodiecode : I know it is a big ask but is it possible for a working code ? I'm working meanwhile , thought a working code will give me a good head start for my next self assignment.. Just wanted to get a look and feel how the RUby experts approach and complete this problem, many thanks..

Comment: @DanHilton, should fix the holder: not capitalised, there is a closing bracket missing and the hash must be inside an array. It should look like: `holder = [{:state => "Texas", :cities=>[{:name => "Antonio", :data=>{"Ron"=>"26", "Rock"=>"23", "Jake"=>"33"}}]}]`

Comment: @Rookie1999, Dan posted already a working code, but you need to review or handle you data structure to be a nested hash. Or you can use YAML or JSON format, unless you want to write your own code. But better to stick with shared standards. Maybe you can post the **raw log file**, so we can see why you ended up with your _`Holder`_ (which is an unknown format).

Comment: @iGian : Sorry for the delayed response. I've added the raw log (sample contents) , thank you.